# Ruby on Rails image_tag puts two <img> tags in my HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I'm still fairly new to Ruby on Rails.  I replaced a image field with the Ruby image_tag.  When I tried to resize the image using CSS, I noticed there was extra blank space below the image...after inspecting the element, I saw there were two  tags for the same image, and I'm not sure why.  Has anyone else seen this happen?

Here is what I put into my code:

```
<%= image_tag (post.image_url), id: "post-image", class: "img-responsive" %>
```

And here is what I see when I inspect the image element:

```
<img id="post-image" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.mypigeonforge.com/uploadedImages/Business/215LodgeCabin(1).jpg" alt="215lodgecabin(1)">
<img id="post-image" class="img-responsive" src="">
```

I have no idea why this is happening...any help would be fantastic.  Also, if I have been vague in any way, I apologize.  This is my first question.

Thank you!!

Edit: Here is the code I used:

**index.html.erb**

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Posts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Posted</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
          <%= render partial: 'post', locals: { post: post } %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

**_post.html.erb**

```html
<% cache post do %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.image_url, id: "post-image", class: "img-responsive")  %>
    <p><%= post.title %></p>
    <p><%= post.content %></p>
    <p><%= post.posted %></p>
    <%= link_to 'Show', post %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you add the whole code of your view?

Comment: Make sure its not in a double loop. Also, Paste the code where scoping it...

Comment: Hi, I have added the code from my view.  Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I never saved my file after adding the `<div class=container>` to my file.  After reloading, I saw that there was only a single  tag.  Thanks and sorry again.